# Using Java to parse text based on keywords

Tags: java, algorithm, parsing

Basically, I got a file containing details about people, each person separated by a new line, e.g
"

```
name Marioka address 97 Garderners Road birthday 12-11-1982 \n
name Ada Lovelace gender woman\n
name James address 65 Watcher Avenue
```

" and so on..

And, I would like to parse them to [Keyword : Value] pair array, such as

```
{[Name, Marioka], [Address, 97 Gardeners Road], [Birthday, 12-11-1982]},
{[Name, Ada Lovelace], [Gender, Woman]}, and so on....
```

and so on. The keywords will be a set of defined words, in above case: name, address, birthday, gender, etc...

What is the best way to do this?

This is how I did it, it works but was wondering whether there are better solutions.

```
    private Map<String, String> readRecord(String record) {
        Map<String, String> attributeValuePairs = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(record);
        String attribute = "", value = ""; 

        /* 
         * 1. Scan each word. 
         * 2. Find an attribute keyword and store it at "attribute".
         * 3. Following words will be stored as "value" until the next keyword is found.
         * 4. Return value-attribute pairs as HashMap
         */

        while(scanner.hasNext()) {
            String word = scanner.next();
            if (this.isAttribute(word)) {
                if (value.trim() != "") {
                    attributeValuePairs.put(attribute.trim(), value.trim());
                    value = "";
                }
                attribute = word;
            } else {
                value += word + " ";
            }
        }
        if (value.trim() != "") attributeValuePairs.put(attribute, value);

        scanner.close();
        return attributeValuePairs;
    }

    private boolean isAttribute(String word) {
        String[] attributes = {"name", "patientId", 
            "birthday", "phone", "email", "medicalHistory", "address"};
        for (String attribute: attributes) {
            if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(attribute)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What's the worst way you have tried?

Comment: `What is the best way to do this?` I think you should write a program for this task... Then if you're stuck with something, we will help you out.

Comment: What if someone has a name or an address that contains one of the keywords?

Comment: @ppeterka I've added my code above, but not really happy with it as it looks bit messy.

Comment: @rolve lets assume it will never happen :S

Comment: `value.trim() != ""` won't do what you expect it to do. to compare strings you have to use `.equals()`. and to check if a string is not empty, use `value.trim().length() > 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract values from a string, use regular expressions. I expect you to know how to read each line from a file and how to build up an array with the results.

Still this is not a good solution, since it doesn't work if any of the keywords are included in the name or address... But that's what you asked for...

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("name (.+) address (.+) birthday (.+)");

        String text = "name Marioka address 97 Garderners Road birthday 12-11-1982";

        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

        if (m.matches()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1) + "\n" + m.group(2) + "\n"
                    + m.group(3));
        } else {
            System.out.println("String does not match");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what if it doesn't match the string? such as birthday isn't on the line?

Comment: @PrototypeStark there is no error handling in my code. This is expected to be a hint in the right direction, because we get too little details from the question

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ArrayList<String> keywords = new ArrayList<String>();
    keywords.add("name");
    keywords.add("address");
    keywords.add("birthday");
    keywords.add("gender");
    String s[] = "name James address 65 Watcher Avenue".trim().split(" ");
    Map<String,String> m = new HashMap<String,String>();
    for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++){

        if(keywords.contains(s[i])){
            System.out.println(s[i]);

            String key =s[i];
            StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
            i++;
            if(i<s.length){
            while(!(keywords.contains(s[i]))){

                System.out.println("i "+i);
                if(i<s.length-1){
                b.append(s[i] + " ");
                }
                i++;
                if(i>=s.length){
                    b.append(s[i-1]);
                    break;
                }
            }
            }
            m.put(key, b.toString());
            i--;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(m);
```

Just add the keywords that you want to identify to the arraylist named `keywords` and it will work.

EDITED: Note that it will not generate output "if someone has a name or an address that contains one of the keywords"

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to put the data into a map, this way you can set a key value 
("name" : "Marioka")

```
Map<String,String> mp=new HashMap<String, String>();
    // adding or set elements in Map by put method key and value pair
    mp.put("name", "nameData");
    mp.put("address", "addressData")...etc
```

Answer (score 0):

This requires you to (pseudo-code):

```
1.  >Read a line
2.  >Split it by a delimiter(' ' in your case)
2.5 >Map<String,String> mp = new HashMap<String,String>();
3.  >for(int i = 0; i < splitArray.length; i += 2){
      try{
        mp.put(splitArray[i],splitArray[i+1]);
      }catch(Exception e){ System.err.println("Syntax Error"); }
4.  >Bob's your uncle, Fanny's your aunt.
```

Although you will have to modify your data file to say ';' = space. Such as

```
name Ada;Lovelace
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the file line by line and call the getKeywordValuePairs() method on each line.

```
public class S{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getKeywordValuePairs("name Marioka address 97 Garderners Road birthday 12-11-1982",
                new String[]{
                    "name", "address", "birthday", "gghghhjgghjhj"
                }));
    }

    public static String getKeywordValuePairs(String text, String keywords[]) {

        ArrayList<String> keyWordsPresent = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> indicesOfKeywordsPresent = new ArrayList<>();

        // finding the indices of all the keywords and adding them to the array
        // lists only if the keyword is present
        for (int i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
            int index = text.indexOf(keywords[i]);
            if (index >= 0) {
                keyWordsPresent.add(keywords[i]);
                indicesOfKeywordsPresent.add(index);
            }
        }

        // Creating arrays from Array Lists
        String[] keywordsArray = new String[keyWordsPresent.size()];
        int[] indicesArray = new int[indicesOfKeywordsPresent.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < keywordsArray.length; i++) {
            keywordsArray[i] = keyWordsPresent.get(i);
            indicesArray[i] = indicesOfKeywordsPresent.get(i);
        }


        // Sorting the keywords and indices arrays based on the position where the keyword appears
        for (int i = 0; i < indicesArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < indicesArray.length - 1 - i; j++) {
                if (indicesArray[i] > indicesArray[i + 1]) {
                    int temp = indicesArray[i];
                    indicesArray[i] = indicesArray[i + 1];
                    indicesArray[i + 1] = temp;
                    String tempString = keywordsArray[i];
                    keywordsArray[i] = keywordsArray[i + 1];
                    keywordsArray[i + 1] = tempString;
                }
            }
        }

        // Creating the result String
        String result = "{";
        for (int i = 0; i < keywordsArray.length; i++) {
            result = result + "[" + keywordsArray[i] + ",";
            if (i == keywordsArray.length - 1) {
                result = result + text.substring(indicesArray[i] + keywordsArray[i].length()) + "]";
            } else {
                result = result + text.substring(indicesArray[i] + keywordsArray[i].length(), indicesArray[i + 1]) + "],";
            }
        }
        result = result + "}";
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a different solution altogether,exploring power for `Java regular expressions and Enum` to read& parse it in to pojo which is future proof solution.

Step -1 : Define your Enum ( you can extend the enum to add all required keys)

```
public enum PersonEnum {
  name { public void set(Person d,String name) {  d.setName(name) ;} },
  address { public void set(Person d,String address) {  d.setAddress(address); } },
  gender { public void set(Person d,String address) {  d.setOthers(address); } };
  public void set(Person d,String others) { d.setOthers(others);  }
}
```

Step-2 : Define your pojo class( if you does not need pojo you can alter enum to use `HashMap`)

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String others;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public String getOthers() {
        return others;
    }
    public void setOthers(String others) {
        this.others = others;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name+"==>"+address+"==>"+others;
    }
```

Step-2: Here is  parser

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        String inputs ="name Marioka address 97 Garderners Road birthday 12-11-1982\n name Ada Lovelace gender" +
                " woman address London\n name James address 65 Watcher Avenue";
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputs);
        List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            List<String> filtereList=splitLines(line, "name|address|gender");
            Iterator< String> lineIterator  = filtereList.iterator();
            Person p = new Person();
            while(lineIterator.hasNext()){
                PersonEnum pEnum = PersonEnum.valueOf(lineIterator.next());
                pEnum.set(p, lineIterator.next());
            }
            personList.add(p);
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static List<String> splitLines(String inputText, String pString) {
    Pattern pattern =Pattern.compile(pString);
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(inputText);
    List<String> filteredList = new ArrayList<String>();
    int start = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        add(inputText.substring(start, m.start()),filteredList);
        add(m.group(),filteredList);
        start = m.end();
    }
    add(inputText.substring(start),filteredList);
    return filteredList;
}
public static void add(String text, List<String> list){
    if(text!=null && !text.trim().isEmpty()){
        list.add(text);
    }
}
```

Note: You would need to define possible enum constants in your PersonEnum, otherwise you would need to take measures to prevent `InvalidArgumentException`

```
eg: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class com.sa.PersonEnum.address
```

Otherwise, this could be one of the best java(OOP) solution I can suggest
Cheers!